# 3 option select set value from database remove onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, select, onchange

I have 3 select option that load values depending on each other

My first select is `Continent` it has the value of continent on load second select is `Country` this select will be loaded on change of continent then last select is `City` this will be loaded on change of country it works fine

Currently because of the onchange event of the the select statement when i load data in the select from database it is not showing the correct data because the one that it is showing is the data when the on change event.

My question is how do i stop the onchange event of the 3 select option so that i can load data from database i was thinking that stopping the onchange is the best way to load data from database. If there are any other option to load data on these select i will gladly try it.

Comment: You should load `Continent` select on page load from database and then create a change function for `Continent` and in this function you should call an ajax and in success function load `country` select box and load `city` like this way

Comment: actually that is what i am doing i load the data from ajax request. it is working ok. the problem is when i want to put data into the select from database for example i will search for one entry combination is `Asia,Japan,Tokyo` this will not be result it will still show the data from onchange event on document.ready. I hope i am making my self sorry for bad english. English is not my Native tongue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to stop an event from propagation in jQuery we have multiple option, like [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/), [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/).

now in the onchange funciton use the methods to stop propagation and load values from your database using [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method.

But i would recommend have onchange events on Continent and country, so that whenever they are changed just fill the respective child values from database using ajax in the onchange function. there will be no need to stop propagation.

Answer (score 0):

I made a example code for your state.

```html
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>:: Script Test Page ::</title>
    <script language='javascript'>
    function changeContient()
    {
        var selectItem = document.getElementById('contient').value;

        if ( selectItem=='1' )
        {
            // select database, using ajax.
            // add data into country option. under code is example data.
            var country = document.getElementById('country');
            country.options[0] = new Option('1-country1','1-country1');
            country.options[1] = new Option('1-country2','1-country2');
            country.options[2] = new Option('1-country3','1-country3');
        }
        else if ( selectItem=='2' )
        {
            // select database, using ajax.
            // add data into country option. under code is example data.
            var country = document.getElementById('country');
            country.options[0] = new Option('2-country1','2-country1');
            country.options[1] = new Option('2-country2','2-country2');
            country.options[2] = new Option('2-country3','2-country3');
        }
        else if ( selectItem=='3' )
        {
            // select database, using ajax.
            // add data into country option. under code is example data.
            var country = document.getElementById('country');
            country.options[0] = new Option('3-country1','3-country1');
            country.options[1] = new Option('3-country2','3-country2');
            country.options[2] = new Option('3-country3','3-country3');
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    function changeCountry()
    {
        // create soruce like changeContient()
    }
    </script>
</head>
<html>
    <body>
        Contient :
        <select id='contient' onChange='changeContient();'>
            <option value='1'>Contient1</option>
            <option value='2'>Contient2</option>
            <option value='3'>Contient3</option>
        </select>
        <br/>
        Country :
        <select id='country' onChange='changeCountry();'>
        </select>
        <br/>
    </body>
</html>
```